# What does pvmove do?

Tags: lvm

`man pvmove` says

> pvmove moves the allocated physical extents (PEs) on a source PV to one or more destination
>   PVs. You can optionally specify a source LV in which case only extents used by that LV will be
>   moved to free (or specified) extents on the destination PV. If no destination PV is specified, the
>   normal allocation rules for the VG are used.

What does "moves the allocated physical extents (PEs) on a source PV to one or more destination
PVs" mean?

What is the difference between `pvmove` and `pvresize`? Does `pvmove` shrink a PV and then use the freed up space to enlarge another PV?

There is a device ( a disk or partition) underlying each PV.  Does `pvmove` work along with another command which resizes the underlying devices of the two PVs involved?

Thanks.

Comment: Two nice examples of pvmove for further reading: [Removing an Old Disk](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/removeadisk.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does "*moves the allocated physical extents (PEs) on a source PV to one or more destination PVs*" mean?

It means what it says. The extents (blocks of data) in one PV are moved to another one. For example, if you have two PVs `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` for a VG you can move the extents from `/dev/sda1` to `/dev/sdb1`). Assuming you had enough space on `/dev/sdb1` this would allow you to remove `/dev/sda1` from the VG, possibly even removing the entire `/dev/sda` from the system.

> What is the difference between pvmove and pvresize? Does pvmove shrink a PV and then use the freed up space to enlarge another PV

`pvmove` moves data from one physical device in a VG to another. `pvresize` changes the size used by a PV. An example from the man page suggests this might be done after changing the size of a partition with `fdisk`.

> Does pvmove work along with another command which resizes the underlying devices of the two PVs involved?

`pvresize` resizes a PV. `pvmove` moves the extents (data blocks) from one PV to another.